How to prevent accidental window resizing when touching the top bar in Ubuntu 24.04?
I'm encountering an issue in Ubuntu 24.04 where certain applications such as Firefox use the top bar as the title bar. Whenever I accidentally touch the top bar and drag, it resizes the window, which can be quite frustrating.
Previously, in Ubuntu 22.04, I didn't experience this level of responsiveness. I'd like to know how to address this issue by either:

Disabling the functionality where touching the top bar resizes the window (I prefer using the minimize button to minimize windows).
Adjusting the sensitivity to make it less responsive.

Actually, it's not even necessary to drag anything: if you just open a folder, for example, and just left click once on the top bar then it resizes the window!

Excellent question ... I just wished the Ubuntu UI overlords would realize nobody wants such an auto windows resize ... or do some folks ?

Assuming you actually mean "enhanced tiling", turning it off didn't stop windows auto-maximizing when you're dragging a window and accidentally get too near the screen edge.
There is a setting under Multitasking for active screen edges. Turning that off didn't stop it either.
Seems like something in 24.04 is broken.

Does this answer your question? How to disable Ubuntu 24.04's toggle maximize on titlebar single click?

I was also struggling with this behaviour, and found disabling the Enhanced Tiling option to work for me.


this is the way.

Thank god you can turn it off. I'm used to clicking the blank space in the browsers tab bar to unfocus the web page. I went nearly insane with this new behavior.

I just want to know who uses this "feature" for it to be turned on by default.

Ubuntu is making it "Windows like". Like it or not :) Thanks for the turning off Advanced Tiling post!

easy actually just turn off enhanced tailing off in settings... very annoying feature!

idk who downvoted this (please provide the reason too), but I also fixed this behavior by turning off enhanced tiling.

typo ?   I do not see any entry in Settings on 24.04 ... in Settings have searched  for tiling  ,  enhanced ,  tailing ... anyone ?

@ScottStensland Open Settings, navigate to "Ubuntu Desktop", scroll down to bottom. You should see the same as the screenshot in the answer from Jadeia.

Seems like a misunderstanding here. The advanced tiling off fix didn't work for me, but I found the setting under multitasking->active screen edges set to off.
This should do until they invent the "don't do stupid stuff" toggle :-)

Using the 24.04 one here, this accidental resizing was fixed in the new update.
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

will fix the problem here if you want to keep the tiling feature.
